# What happens to a woman devotee who views Krishna as her husband/lover?

Tags: krishna, moksha, women, bhakti

It is not uncommon for a female devotee to see Krishna as her lover/husband. (Mira bai was one example).
Theoretically, what happens to them if their devotion is true? Do they get merged with Radha/Lakshmi and become a wife of Krishna? (If they get Moksha)

Comment: They attain the lord. There is no merger with anyone.

Comment: Bhagavatam and its rasa leela answeres this clearly right? What specifically is your question?

Answer (score 1):

the gopikas saw lord krishna as their lover or husband. so they had got a place at goloka for eternity where they will serve lord krishna in madhurya rasa. it is the highest reward possible for any jiva. among all devotees of lord krishna, gopikas are the best.